# java.lang.AssertionError: Expecting actual not to be null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Создал рест апи приложение и теперь начинаю учить тестирование, выдает ошибку на этот тест

```
import com.product.controller.ProductController;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;


@SpringBootTest(classes = ProductController.class)
public class ProductControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProductController productController;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception{
     (20 строка)  assertThat(productController).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

все сделал как говорится на сайте spring.io, но пишет что тест провален

controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/product/")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

@RequestMapping(value = "",method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getAllProducts(){
        List<Product> products = this.productService.getAll();

       if (products.isEmpty()){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(products,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

pom

```
    <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

сервис класс

```
public interface ProductService {

    Product getById(BigInteger _id);

    void save(Product product);

    List<Product> getAll();

    List<Long> getAllCategoryIds();

}
```

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    CategoryIdRepository categoryIdRepository;

    @Override
    public Product getById(BigInteger _id) {
       return productRepository.findOne(_id);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Product product) {
        productRepository.save(product);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Product> getAll(){
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Long> getAllCategoryIds() {
        return categoryIdRepository.findAllId();
    }

}
```

Comment: у меня тоже самое было, пока не использовал junit c актуальной версией

Comment: теперь использую тот же спринг бут стартер и добавил Junit 4.12 версии, не работает, а как вы делаете?

Comment: хмм... я через maven все прописал и сработало

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34382889/spring-unit-test-with-assertions-exceptions-java

Comment: У тебя нулл значение

Comment: прочитал статью, понял что контроллер возвращает null, но не понимаю ведь у меня прописано что он возвращает строку по идее такого не должно быть

Comment: debug скинь сюда

Comment: https://gist.github.com/artem-kurilko/c5ea73e33b731cf8f271969552aba474

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь эту аннотацию над тестовым классом, должно помочь

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

Comment: не помогло, писало добавить @springconfiguration классу теста, добавил но программа как будто не видит его

Comment: Попробуй сделать так - добавить в скобках в аннотацию теста имя класса, который тестируешь, чтобы не поднимать весь контекст @SpringBootTest(classes = HomeController.class), импорт аннотации Test сделать из пакета org.junit.jupiter.api.Test, а также можешь убрать явный импорт junit4, зависимость spring-boot-starter-test уже подтягивает junit5

Comment: Сделал все равно выдает ошибку, я обновил в вопросе логи и код, может я неправильно настроил контроллер? не знаю почему автоматически присваивает нал

Comment: Все правильно ProductService никак не инжектится и не создается тестовым контекстом. Тебе необходимо либо замокать ProductService с аннотацией @MockBean в тестовом классе и при вызове этого сервиса делать mock методов, либо указать в конфигурации контекста его @SpringBootTest(classes = {ProductController.class, ProductService.class}). Во втором случае нужно понимать, что если в ProductService есть зависимости, которые инжектит spring, то их также либо замокать, либо указать в настройках контекста в аннотации SpringBootTest

Comment: product service не имеет спринг зависимостей, но он имплементируется класом productserviceimpl и там уже есть зависимости, я поменял лог на этот класс, пересислили в спринг бут тест все классы которые были задействованы не помогло, наверное это глупо

Comment: В ProductServiceImpl есть как минимум две зависимости  (ProductRepository, CategoryIdRepository), которые в случае создания объекта сервиса нужно или мокать или заботиться об инжекте оных в сервис. Если у тебя происходит тестирование именно контроллера, то посмотри в сторону @WebMvcTest (https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/). Если же цель теста - протестировать сервис, то контроллер не нужно включать в цепочку тестирования, а только собирать контекст из сервиса и мокать репозитории.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104422/discussion-between-petrovich-and--).